# Converting a string to value of same string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a piece of code with a menu that allows for a couple different user inputs, but have currently backed myself into a corner.

Below is a sample of the menu:

```
while True:
    choice = input("""\nChoose option:

    0: Back
    1: Print df_bhole
    2: Print df_soil_descr_ocr

Chosen option: """)

    if choice == '0':
        break
    elif choice == '1':
        printdf('df_bholes.csv',bh_params_dtypes)
    elif choice == '2':
        printdf('df_soil_desc_ocr.csv',soil_desc_ocr_dtypes)
```

This launches the code printdf which can be seen below.

```
def printdf (filename,parameters):

try:
    df = pd.read_csv('df_bholes.csv', sep='\t', index_col=0, dtype=bh_params_dtypes)
    print(df)
        except:
            try:
                df=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
                print(df)
            except:
                print("This dataframe has not yet been created")
```

The problem I have with this code is that "df", in the event that no .csv file is found, is a string, due to "filename" being one, and as such the print will just be df_bhole or df_soil_descr_ocr.

The output i really want is the entire dataframe saved in the name df_bhole.

I've seen people talk about dictionaries, but it seems that these would require me to hardcode options depending on the input from filename.

Is there an option to simply take 'df_bhole' and turn it into df_bhole?

Comment: It only prints that the dataframe doesn't exists if there's no .csv file to read data from, and if the dataframe doesn't exist anywhere in the memory of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use eval()

```
eval('df_bhole')
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing an explanation of how this would help and a more complete code example.

Comment: better use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html)

Comment: @ChristianEmilJohansen just be aware of [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice).